# Using OFFSET in dynamic named range in chart in excel 2010 causes crash

Tags: excel, charts, excel-formula, excel-2007, excel-2010

I created a workbook in Excel 2007 that has many dynamic named ranges.  They all use the OFFSET function.  An example is name of range is "date", worksheet is "Example", and Refers to is `=OFFSET('Example'!$N$3;0;0;COUNTA(!$N:$N);1)`.  I use these dynamic named ranges as the data selection for charts.

My issue is that when I attempt to open my workbook in Excel 2010, Excel immediately crashes.  I determined the issue was with using my dynamic named ranges for the chart data selection.  I created a new workbook and created the named dynamic range (like described above) with no issue.  But the moment I set the named dynamic range as the data selection for a chart Excel crashed!

Any idea if I'm doing something wrong?  Any idea for a workaround?

Comment: Could you share a sample file that shows that behaviour? Use a public file sharing service and post the URL here.

Comment: I've uploaded a sample here: http://ge.tt/3Gu6fBr1/v/0

To enact the "bug" set the chart data in the first chart to x-series to `=Sheet1!date`, and the y-series to `=Sheet1!pctOk`.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue with some help from the [Microsoft Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/using-offset-in-dynamic-named-range-in-chart-in/905baf57-f498-4123-8039-4c96a0d3ac86?tm=1408042740893).  TUrns out that Excel 2007 can handle `=OFFSET('Example'!$N$3;0;0;COUNTA(!$N:$N);1)` **but** Excel 2010 can't.  You need to explicitly name the sheet in the `COUNTA` function.  So, in Excel 2010 it should look like: `=OFFSET('Example'!$N$3;0;0;COUNTA('Example'!$N:$N);1)`.

Comment: I'm wondering why you thought you didn't need to name the sheet. That was the first thing I thought of.